# Send POST request from one service to another in Amazon ECS

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2, microservices, amazon-ecs

I have a Node-Express website running on a microservices based architecture. I deployed the microservices on Amazon ECS cluster with one EC2 instance. The microservices sit behind an Application Load Balancer that routes external traffic correctly to the services. This system is working as expected except for one problem: I need to make a POST request from one service to the other. I am trying to use axios for this but I don't know what url to post to in axios. When testing locally, I just used `axios.post('http://localhost:3000/service2',...)` inside service 1 but how should I do it here?

Comment: Which networking option are you using in ECS cluster ? bridge/awsvpc ?

Comment: @ImranArshad Right now, I am using bridge. But as I am reading aws docs figuring this out, I think awsvpc is what I need. Am I right? I am also reading about Route 53 but it's a paid service and I am looking for free options.

Comment: Route 53 is for service discovery and is optional . Did you try accessing the service via Load balancer ? So one service calling other via LoadBalancer ?

Comment: @ImranArshad I tried calling `axios.get('/service2/method'...)` from inside service 1, but I am getting a `504 Gateway Timeout` error

Comment: I assume your load balancer is public ? try calling your service using application load balancer DNS.

Comment: you can use linking, to call the other service B from service A

Comment: you cant use localhost, as loclhost point to service A no matter what the port u mentioned, another option is to use the private of from service A to access service B

Answer (score 0):

So There are various ways. 
**1. Use Application Load Balancer behind the service**
In this method, you put your micro services behind the load balancer(s) and to send request, you give load balancer URL. You can have path based routing for same load balancer or you can use multiple load balancers.

**2. Use Service Discovery** 
In this method, you let your requester discover it. Now Service discovery can be done in various way like [using ALB or Route 53 or ECS or Key Value Store or Configuration Management or Third Party Software](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/whitepapers/latest/microservices-on-aws/service-discovery.html) such as [Consul](https://www.consul.io/intro/index.html)